# python program to generate n*n matrix from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate a n*n matrix from user inputing the value of `n` and elements of the matrix.

Following is the code:

```
n=int(input("Enter the matrix size"))

import numpy as np

#initialise nxn matrix with zeroes
mat=np.zeros((n,n))

#input each row at a time,with each element separated by a space
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        mat[i][j]=input()
print(mat)
```

but I am getting output like this

```
[[1. 2.]

 [3. 4.]]
```

with a . (point) after the numbers which I don't want. Is there any way to get this with using loops and array only not `NumPy`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost close. You just have to declare the datatype as `dtype=int` while initializing your matrix as

```
mat=np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)
```

and then you won't have dots but just

```
[[1 2]
[3 4]]
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because `np.zeros` by default assigns it's values to `float`. To change that replace line:
`mat=np.zeros((n,n))`

with:

`mat=np.zeros((n,n), dtype=int)`

It will give you output you want.

Also good practice is to use `help()` on used methods, to know what can be done with them, like in this example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
n =  int(input())

mat=[[int(input()) for x in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

You can convert above list into numpy as

```
np_mat = numpy.asarray(mat)
```

If you want to input each row at a time,with each element separated by a space, you can do like this.

```
mat=[list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m=int(input("enter matrix row size"))
n=int(input("enter matrix column size"))

Mat1 = []
Mat2 = []
Mat3 = []

for i in range(m):
    Mat1.append([0]*n)
print (Mat1)

for j in range(m):
    Mat2.append([0]*n)
print (Mat2)

for k in range(m):
    Mat3.append([0]*n)
print (Mat3)


for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print ('enter in Matrix 1 row: ',i+1,' column: ',j+1)
        Mat1[i][j] = int(input())

for k in range(m):
    for l in range(n):
        print ('enter in MAtrix 2 row: ',k+1,' column: ',l+1)
        Mat2[k][l] = int(input())

for p in range (m):
    for q in range (n):
        Mat3[p][q]=Mat1[p][q]+Mat2[p][q]
        #print(Mat1[p][q]+Mat2[p][q])`z

print (Mat1)        
print (Mat2)
print (Mat3)
```